# How do I call a C function from a Perl program?

Tags: perl

`test.c`:

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+b);
}
```

`test.pl`:

```
# how do I call sum here?
```

Comment: See http://www.fourtheye.org/xs_tutorial.html

Comment: AFAIK, you need to use XS for this: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html

Answer (score 17):

```
use Inline C => <<'__END_OF_C__';

    int sum(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a+b);
    }

__END_OF_C__

say sum($x,$y);
```

Comment: I assume if I want my Perl code to use some C API (from a compiled object) the only way is XS?

Comment: @soulSurfer2010 - On Windows, `Win32::API` has a mechanism to call functions in a DLL.

Comment: You could use Inline. It allows you to specify objects to link to. Add `LIBS => '-lmyclib'` to the `use` line.

Comment: Does `Inline C` allow you to use macros?

Comment: @Alexej Magura, Yes. In fact, the Perl API make heavy use of them.

Comment: There's now [FFI::Platypus](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus) as well, which is like a portable Win32::API.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need `XS`. It's quite involved, so it's best to look at the official manual and tutorial pages for it:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html